# Login com Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, login, console

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de Login com o firebase, gostaria de saber como posso bloquear uma chamada de XMLHttpRequest via console do navegador?
O login é feito via ajax, quando recebo as informações de autenticação do firebase, faço o request para a página principal. Existe alguma forma de bloquar essa chamada apenas utilizando Javascript ?

Obrigado.